# Common onclick listner inside a dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, onclicklistener

i am working on an application which is managing daily expenses. i need to add a feature which is , a user can calculate the sum of more expenses under one category. [simply when a user wants to add an expense, (lets say food) he needs to calculate the all expenses for food and add the total amount for food category.

to do this, i use an button. when user tap that button,a small calculator pops out.(using Dialog).[image]

my problem is, i want to use a common  `Onclicklistner` to the buttons inside the dialog.how can i do it.?

here is the code i am using

```
protected void popUpCalculator(){
    final Dialog dialog_cal = new Dialog(NewExpence.this);
    dialog_cal.setTitle("Calculator");
    dialog_cal.setContentView(R.layout.calculater);

    initialiseButtons(dialog_cal);

    dialog_cal.show();
}

    public void initialiseButtons(Dialog d){
    num0 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btn0);

    num1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    num2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    num3 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    num4 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    num5 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    num6 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    num7 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    num8 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    num9 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btn9);
    numC = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnC);
    dot = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnDot);
    opDiv = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
    opMul = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnMulti);
    opMinus = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
    opPlus = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.BtnAdd);
    CalculatorValue = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.Value);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     if(v.getId()==R.id.calButton){
        popUpCalculator();
    }
   }
```

And my logic for the calculator is something like this.it should be the code segments which is placed inside the `onclickListner`

```
String buttonPressed = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
             if(DIGITS.contains(buttonPressed)){
                if(userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber){
                    if (buttonPressed.equals(".") && CalculatorValue.getText().toString().contains(".")) {
                        // ERROR PREVENTION
                        // Eliminate entering multiple decimals
                    } else {
                        CalculatorValue.append(buttonPressed);
                    }
                }else{
                     if (buttonPressed.equals(".")) {
                            // ERROR PREVENTION
                            // This will avoid error if only the decimal is hit before an operator, by placing a leading zero
                            // before the decimal
                         CalculatorValue.setText(0 + buttonPressed);
                        } else {
                            CalculatorValue.setText(buttonPressed);
                        }
                    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber=true;
                }
             }
        }
```

EDIT

the Accepted answer is the best approach

but i have made it like this..

```
Button [] buttonIds = {num0,num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,numC,dot,opDiv,opMinus,opMul,opPlus};


    for(int x=0;x<buttonIds.length;x++){
        ((Button)buttonIds[x]).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

both ways are correct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you registered `onClickListener` to your buttons?

You can also do this way

```
protected void popUpCalculator(){
   final Dialog dialog_cal = new Dialog(NewExpence.this);
   dialog_cal.setTitle("Calculator");
   dialog_cal.setContentView(R.layout.calculater);

   int buttonIds[] = { R.id.btn0 , R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3,
                       R.id.btn4 , R.id.btn5, R.id.btn6, R.id.btn6,
                       R.id.btn7 , R.id.btn8, R.id.btn9, R.id.btnC,
                       R.id.btnDot , R.id.btnDiv, R.id.btnMulti, 
                       R.id.btnMinus , R.id.BtnAdd , R.id.Value }

   for(int i=0; i<buttonIds.length; i++){
        dialog_cal.findViewById(buttonIds[i]).setOnClickListener(this);
       // use this if you are implementing View.OnClickListener
   }

   dialog_cal.show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   if(v.getId() == R.id.calButton){
      popUpCalculator();
   }
   // for other buttons chech their ids and write the respective code
}
```

Comment: Moreover, use `switch-case` instead `if` comparison in `onClick`.

Comment: @Kaustubh buttonIds[i] is an int. setOnClickListener() applies to view. I think you meant by d.findViewById(buttonIds[i]).setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: @SunilKumarSahoo thanks for pointing out.. i was in a hurry to post the ans hence missed imp part :D